# How to get openright only at frontmatter?

Tags: front-matter

I need to use openright **only** at front matter. Using

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{book}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{First Chapter at front matter}  % This must be page i
\chapter{Second Chapter at front matter}  % This must be page iii
\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter at main matter}  % This must be page 1
\chapter{Second Chapter at main matter}  % This must be page 2
\end{document}
```

I got openright in all document and using

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, oneside]{book}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{First Chapter at front matter}  % This must be page i
\chapter{Second Chapter at front matter}  % This must be page iii
\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter at main matter}  % This must be page 1
\chapter{Second Chapter at main matter}  % This must be page 2
\end{document}
```

I got openany in all the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this after `\frontmatter`:

```
\makeatletter
\@openrightfalse
\makeatother
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{book}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{First Chapter at front matter}  % This must be page i
\chapter{Second Chapter at front matter}  % This must be page iii
\makeatletter
\@openrightfalse
\makeatother
\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter at main matter}  % This must be page 1
\chapter{Second Chapter at main matter}  % This must be page 2
\end{document}
```

[image]