# Can Even Pages Be Right Pages?

Tags: numbering, page-numbering, counters

SETCOUNTER in BOOK changes page numbers as well as directions—odd pages are right pages and vice versa. This is an example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{TEXT}
\author{TEXT}
\date{TEXT}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
EMPTY PAGE
\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage
SECOND PAGE: MUST BE RIGHT BUT LEFT SO INCORRECT
\setcounter{page}{2}\clearpage
EMPTY PAGE
\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage
THIRD PAGE: MUST BE RIGHT AND RIGHT SO CORRECT
\setcounter{page}{3}
\mainmatter
\chapter{TEXT}
TEXT
\end{document}
```

I must insert an empty page and use the third page as Page ii, which must be a right page. Is an even-but-right page or an odd-but-left page available?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your `SECOND PAGE: MUST BE RIGHT BUT LEFT SO INCORRECT` is on a right page with page number `ii` so I see no problem. How are you viewing your PDF? Iirc you want to have your titlepage separated and from then on a double-page view…

Comment: I use TeXworks and [LaTeX Base](https://latexbase.com/). The third page locates "ii" at the northwest corner, while the fifth page locates "iii" at the northeast corner.

Comment: You shouldn't confuse your readers by putting an even numbered page on the right. Page `ii` is wrong.

Comment: @TeXnician page ii should be a left page.

Comment: @TeXnician it is not only about the headers, the page geometry is messed up too.

Comment: Anything is "possible" if you redefine enough macros, but in any publishing style based on European practice, odd numbered pages are ALWAYS on the right and even numbered pages on the left. That has been a fixed rule for hundreds of years before TeX was invented.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but for the pages in FRONTMATTER, I must use only the front side of each paper with consecutive page numbering and put Pages ii, iv, and vi—as well as Pages i, iii, and v—on the right. Then MAINMATTER will use both sides. Must I give up this style?

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213515/579) provides a mechanism (using the toggle `\@openright`) to switch between one-sided and two-sided pages.  I'm not sure how to get an even page number on a right-hand page, and am currently unable to experiment.